# Align CSS toggle switch

Tags: html, css

Using [this](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/) tool I was able to create a CSS toggle switch, but when placed on my page it's slightly off at the top and can't seem to be able to find what's causing it.

I'm not so experienced with CSS but from what I understand the onoffswitch-switch class refers to the circle that moves on click and onoffswitch-inner refer to each option so it has to be either onoffswitch or onoffswitch-label, but I don't see any margin option that could cause this and the start button doesn't have any either.

The toggle switch originally came with

```
display: block;
```

which I switched to inline.

[Here](http://codepen.io/dchan/pen/GNQgwz)'s the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no padding or margin set, your checkbox is aligned to the top of its parent element. You can use padding or margin, but I'd suggest adding vertical-align:middle to the onoffswitch class for a more responsive design.

```
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative; width: 105px;
  -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the button stick to the top as well?